# How to create Number arrays:

Tags: python

I want to create simple array of numbers which gives output -

1

22

333

4444

55555

I don't want to create a list because I dont want to see any brackets like [], or ,

I just want the above output

Comment: "I want to create simple array".... "i dont want to create a list" ... which is it?

Comment: okay just the above any way you can - I will view and let you know

Comment: `print(1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555, sep="\n")`. You need to show some effort.

Comment: Thanks very much,  that's what I was missing -sep- .

Comment: I'm new to Python and was using '\n' continously to seperate them but it would'nt work,  was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print_output(number):
  for n in range(1, number+1):
    for i in range(n):
      print(n, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Hello,  Can you explain the above function, in particular the lines,                                                             
1.  for n in range(1, number+1):                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                              
 2.  print(n, end="")

Comment: The outer for loop will iterate 1 through the number you pass into the function. range(start, stop, step) defaults to starting at zero and stops before the specified stop hence the (1, num+1) so we get `1,2,3,4,5` instead of `0,1,2,3,4`. The inner loop is for how many times to print each number. one for 1 and two for 2. Then parameter `end=""` in print says print "" instead of the default newline, "\n", so we can get multiple numbers on one line.

Comment: thanks,  can you add some numbers into that loop, and I can get better understanding, and then I can test it

Comment: It is ready to test. Copy pasta that into your python code and call it like this: `print_output(5)`